# Is there a way to drill down/search directory in dotcms?

Tags: path, dotcms

For example, if I wanted to go to mysite.com/this/is/the/path is there a way to just drill down to that path quickly via some search function? Scrolling through layers and layers of folders is no fun, especially on a siteas big as ours is here at work.

As far as I can tell right now, there doesn't seem to be any kind of search/filtering option, but then again, I may just not have it turned on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (since dotcms 3.2.1) search by url from the content search screen.   See searching for pages under /about-us on the http://demo.dotcms.com site:

[image: Searching Pages in dotCMS]